# OpenId Connect failing with SQL Server Session State

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application running on IIS 8.5/Windows Server 2012. It is using Keycloak for OpenId Connect authentication.

When the session state mode is InProc, this works fine, session authenticates and the cookie is created successfully. However when the session state is in SQL Server mode, it will go into an infinite loop of redirecting to the identity provider and redirecting to the app.

With breakpoints in the OpenId Connect notifications I can confirm that the security token is validated, which leads me to believe that there is an issue serializing something. But I'm unsure what exactly it is, as there are no errors logged. Usually if you try to persist something to session storage that is not serializable then an exception will be thrown.

Is this a known issue, or is there a configuration workaround to deal with it? The SQL session state is in use successfully by other applications which do not authenticate via OpenId Connect.